# facebook login/logout issue in website

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I’ve taken below code from Facebook developer, while login to FB it's showing only logout button not showing user name and profile with logout button. Is it possible to add our own button instead of Facebook login button?

```
<html>
    <head><title>facelogin<title></head>
    <body>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '478566162309261',
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

      // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
      // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
      // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
      // will be handled. 
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
          // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
          // have logged in to the app.
          testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
          // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
          // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
          // like this, for two reasons:
          // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
          // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
          // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
          FB.login();
        } else {
          // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
          // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
          // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
          // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
          // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
          FB.login();
        }

      });
      };

      // Load the SDK asynchronously
      (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
      }(document));

      // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
      // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
      function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
      }
      FB.logout(function(response) {
            // Person is now logged out
        });
    </script>

    <!--
      Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses the JavaScript SDK to
      present a graphical Login button that triggers the FB.login() function when clicked. -->

    <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own button and call [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.3) on click:

```js
document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //do the login
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
            getUserData();
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true});
}, false);
```

Source: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        // FB JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
        FB.init({
            appId: // FB App ID
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
            version: 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
        });

        // Check whether the user already logged in
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //display user data
                getFbUserData();
            }
        });
    };

// Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id))
            return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=FB APP ID";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Facebook login with JavaScript SDK
    function fbLogin() {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // Get and display the user profile data
                getFbUserData();
            } else {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.';
            }
        }, {scope: 'email'});
    }

// Fetch the user profile data from facebook
    function getFbUserData() {
        FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture'},
                function (response) {

                    document.getElementById('fbLink').setAttribute("onclick", "fbLogout()");
                    document.getElementById('fbLink').innerHTML = 'Logout from Facebook';
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.first_name + '!';
                    document.getElementById('userData').innerHTML = '<p><b>FB ID:</b> ' + response.id + '</p><p><b>Name:</b> ' + response.first_name + ' ' + response.last_name + '</p><p><b>Email:</b> ' + response.email + '</p><p><b>Gender:</b> ' + response.gender + '</p><p><b>Locale:</b> ' + response.locale + '</p><p><b>Picture:</b> <img src="' + response.picture.data.url + '"/></p><p><b>FB Profile:</b> <a target="_blank" href="' + response.link + '">click to view profile</a></p>';
                });
    }

// Logout from facebook
    function fbLogout() {
        FB.logout(function () {
            document.getElementById('fbLink').setAttribute("onclick", "fbLogin()");
            document.getElementById('fbLink').innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
//        document.getElementById('fbLink').innerHTML = '<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>';
            document.getElementById('userData').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You have successfully logout from Facebook.';
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.